# Making a price converter with API data

Tags: javascript, html

So far, I've managed to get the price data from the API and showing it in a `h1`. But, I don't know how to get the value from the `h1` and use it in my converter functions. I'm currently multiplying by 100 as an example, but I want to use the price value in the place of 100.

```js
function getElement(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

fetch('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/stellar?localization=false&sparkline=false')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((res) => {
    const market_data = res.market_data;
    getElement('usdprice').innerHTML = "$" + market_data.current_price.usd.toFixed(6);
  });

function calcusd() {
  x = document.getElementById("xlm").value;
  document.getElementById("usd").value = x * 100;
}

function calcxlm() {
  x = document.getElementById("usd").value;
  document.getElementById("xlm").value = x / 100;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="usdprice"></h1>

<div id="Converter">
  <h1>Price Converter</h1>

  <h3>XLM:</h3> <input oninput="calcusd()" onchange="calcusd()" type="number" id="xlm">
  <h3>USD:</h3> <input oninput="calcxlm()" onchange="calcxlm()" type="number" id="usd">
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to use the value in `usdprice` element instead the dummy value 100.

Get the `innerHTML` of the `h1` -> remove the `$` symbol using [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) -> convert it to float using [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) -> multiply it to the input value.

Here's a working snippet:

```js
function getElement(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

fetch('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/stellar?localization=false&sparkline=false')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((res) => {
    const market_data = res.market_data;
    getElement('usdprice').innerHTML = "$" + market_data.current_price.usd.toFixed(6);
  });

function calcusd() {
  let x = getElement("xlm").value;
  getElement("usd").value = x * getUSD();
}

function calcxlm() {
  let x = getElement("usd").value;
  getElement("xlm").value = x / getUSD();
}

function getUSD() {
  try {
    return parseFloat(getElement('usdprice').innerHTML.replace("$", ""));
  } catch {
    return 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="usdprice"></h1>

<div id="Converter">
  <h1>Price Converter</h1>

  <h3>XLM:</h3> <input oninput="calcusd()" onchange="calcusd()" type="number" id="xlm">
  <h3>USD:</h3> <input oninput="calcxlm()" onchange="calcxlm()" type="number" id="usd">

</div>
```